# What is the meaning of the term "whatawow"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

I read this phrase "This person is whattawwow", what does it actually means?

Comment: You must provide source.  Please link to the place where you read this phrase.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a common/standard word, and I (native American English speaker) have never heard it used. Google also gave me no results.

If I had to guess, I would assume it meant "what a wow" and was being used as a generic compliment. I would assume a small pause before the phrase, as it isn't really an adjective, so much as an interjection.

Comment: I see, but there are a few posts with that word as a hashtag on Twitter and Instagram as well. What is the context of such compliment? What feature does it emphasize?

Comment: @JohnaelKorbin Can you give contexts instead? Same As Esther, my Google gives me 0 results. We can't imagine out a context for you.